# MPI send for custom serialized objects (more generic code)

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, mpi

### The question

I am trying to find a proper way to send **custom serialized objects** (not custom MPI structs - see definition below) through MPI. After reading several material and stackoverflow, I have a **working** example which is using `boost::serialization` and sends the serialized objects as `stringstream`. However, my current solution looks a bit **hackish**, see a snapshot below (the full code is attached at the end section).

> **My question:** Can you give an opinion on the current solution and recommend some industry accepted way to send custom serialized objects?

.

> **Restriction:** Unfortunately `boost.mpi` is not an option due to its dependency with `openmpi` which has a TCP related bug on my `ubuntu-xenial` infrastructure. I use only pure `mpich`.

### Custom object definition

> **custom object:** In my example the custom object serializes its `base` class, an `std::vector`, a `boost::shared_ptr` and some other simple variables.

### MPI Send/Rcv snapshot

This is a small program snapshot of how I send/receive the stream.

```
 if (rank == 1) {
        std::stringstream mystream;
        //...more serialization code here

        int len = mystream.str().size();
        MPI_Send( &len, 1, MPI_INT, 1, lentag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        MPI_Send( (void *)mystream.str().c_str(), len, MPI_BYTE, 1, datatag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );

} else if (rank == 1) {
        int len;
        MPI_Recv( &len, 1, MPI_INT, 0, lentag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        char data[len+1];
        MPI_Recv( data, len, MPI_BYTE, 0, datatag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        data[len] = '\0';

        std::stringstream mystream;
        mystream.write((const char*) data, len);

        //...more deserialization code here
}
```

### Program output

This is the program output. You can see that the data are tranferred successfully from `rank 0` to `rank 1`.

```
$ mpirun.mpich -np 2 ./mpidata 
Rank 0 sum in 6
Rank 0 vsize out 4
Rank 0 ptr out 30

Rank 1 sum in 6
Rank 1 vsize in 4
Rank 1 ptr in 30
```

### MPI Send/Rcv full code

The full code is provided below.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/archive/binary_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/binary_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/base_object.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/string.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>

// Forward declaration of class boost::serialization::access
namespace boost {
namespace serialization {
class access;
}
}

class Obj {
public:
    // Serialization expects the object to have a default constructor
    Obj() : d1_(-1), d2_(-2) {}
    Obj(int d1, int d2) : d1_(d1), d2_(d2) {}
    bool operator==(const Obj& o) const {
        return d1_ == o.d1_ && d2_ == o.d2_;
    }

    const int sum() const {return d1_+d2_;}
private:
    int d1_;
    int d2_;

    // Allow serialization to access non-public data members.
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template<typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) {
        ar & d1_ & d2_; // Simply serialize the data members of Obj
    }
};

class ObjChild : public Obj {

private:
    typedef Obj _Super;

public:
    ObjChild() : Obj(),d1_(-1),dv_{1,2},iptr_(new Obj()) {}
    ObjChild(
            int d1,
            int d2,
            int d1new,
            std::vector<int> const& dv,
            boost::shared_ptr<Obj> const& obj
            ) : Obj(d1,d2),d1_(d1new),dv_(dv),iptr_(obj) {}

    const int sum2() const {return d1_ + sum();}
    const int vsize() const {return dv_.size();}
    const int ptrsum() const {return iptr_->sum();}

private:
    int d1_; // Another d1_
    std::vector<int> dv_;
    boost::shared_ptr<Obj> iptr_;

    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    friend class boost::serialization::access;

    template <typename Archive>
    void serialize(Archive& ar, const unsigned version) {
        ar & boost::serialization::base_object<_Super>(*this);
        ar & d1_;
        ar & dv_;
        ar & iptr_;
    }
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
};

int main(int argc,char** argv) {

    int size, rank;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    if (size < 2) {
        if (rank == 0)
            std::cerr << "Require at least 2 tasks" << std::endl;
        MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
    }

   const int lentag=0;
   const int datatag=1;
   if (rank == 0) {

        std::stringstream mystream;

        ObjChild obj(1,3,2,{1,2,3,4},boost::make_shared<Obj>(10,20));

        boost::archive::binary_oarchive oarchive{mystream};
        oarchive << obj;

        std::cout<<"Rank "<< rank << " sum in " << obj.sum2() << std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Rank "<< rank << " vsize out " << obj.vsize() << std::endl;
        std::cout<<"Rank "<< rank << " ptr out " << obj.ptrsum() << std::endl;

        int len = mystream.str().size();
        // Send length, then data
        MPI_Send( &len, 1, MPI_INT, 1, lentag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
        MPI_Send( (void *)mystream.str().c_str(), len, MPI_BYTE, 1, datatag, MPI_COMM_WORLD );


        } else if (rank == 1) {
            int len;
            MPI_Recv( &len, 1, MPI_INT, 0, lentag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

            char data[len+1];
            MPI_Recv( data, len, MPI_BYTE, 0, datatag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
            data[len] = '\0';

            std::stringstream mystream;
            mystream.write((const char*) data, len);

            boost::archive::binary_iarchive iarchive(mystream);

            ObjChild obj;

            iarchive >> obj;

            std::cout<<"Rank "<< rank << " sum in "<< obj.sum2() << std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Rank "<< rank << " vsize in " << obj.vsize() << std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Rank "<< rank << " ptr in " << obj.ptrsum() <<         std::endl;

        }

        MPI_Finalize();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the full code example. While the question is good and answerable, be careful to not invite opinionated answers ("best practices"). Instead focus on tangible goals and specific questions, e.g. *how can I use a cleaner "less hackish" abstraction*?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Boost.Serialization anyway the absolute sensible thing to do is to use Boost.MPI. This will basically hide all the serialization boilerplate from the communication part and look like this:

```
  boost::mpi::environment env;
  boost::mpi::communicator world;
  auto rank = world.rank();

  if (world.size() < 2) {
    if (rank == 0)
      std::cerr << "Require at least 2 tasks" << std::endl;
    MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1);
  }

  const int datatag = 1;
  if (rank == 0) {
    ObjChild obj(1, 3, 2, {1, 2, 3, 4}, boost::make_shared<Obj>(10, 20));

    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " sum in " << obj.sum2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " vsize out " << obj.vsize() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " ptr out " << obj.ptrsum() << std::endl;

    world.send(1, datatag, obj);
  } else if (rank == 1) {
    ObjChild obj;
    world.recv(0, datatag, obj);

    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " sum in " << obj.sum2() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " vsize in " << obj.vsize() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Rank " << rank << " ptr in " << obj.ptrsum() << std::endl;
  }
```

Some types like PODs may benefit from additionally specifying [`is_mpi_datatype`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/mpi/is_mpi_datatype.html), but `ObjChild` doesn't qualify due to the pointer.

Unfortunately, despite the good reputation of boost, Boost.MPI appears to be barely maintained with fundamental issues not being addressed or even discussed. Be particularly careful with non-blocking communication of serialized objects. So I can't necessarily recommend Boost.MPI for production code if you are not willing to invest into fixing stuff yourself. Which is probably still better than building it yourself from the ground. Also note that serialization, particularly Boost's implementation is rather slow and may not be suitable for certain HPC use-cases, where it would be better to design the memory layout to not require any serialization or complex packing in the first place.

Comment: I would never recommend to use boost.mpi. The issue is worst than maintaining issue. boost.mpi is not supported by builders... you definitely want a portable solution from cluster to cluster... So hard coding is the best way (in my opinion).

Comment: You can certainly run programs depending on Boost.MPI on various HPC systems - if that is even a goal. If there is already a dependency to Boost.Serialization, the argument is even weaker. It's up to user1221647 to weigh the pro & cons of using Boost.MPI. As I wrote, I have my own share of issues with Boost.MPI.

Comment: @Zulan thank you for the answer. My apologies not to mention that i cannot run boost.mpi due to some openmpi bug. I only use pure MPICH. I would be tempted to try fix the openmpi+boost.mpi and retry your recommendation.

Comment: In case where `boost.mpi` is not an option, do you have any other alternatives in mind?

Comment: Rebuild a similar interface but focus on serializable types only (rather than primitive MPI datatypes) and do only blocking communication (rather than nonblocking).

Comment: @user1221647 was the Open MPI bug reported, either at [https://github.com/open-mpi/ompi](github) or the [https://lists.open-mpi.org/mailman/listinfo/users](Mailing List) ?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet the openmpi error is `tcp_peer_send_blocking: send() to socket 9 failed: Broken pipe (32)` on v1.10.2. In previous versions works fine. It is something related to `#1585`. I remember I found some more than this, but I cannot find it. I can elaborate more offline, if you are interested.

Comment: Have you tried with more recent and supported versions (e.g. v2.1 or v3.0) ? If the error persists, can you please open a github issue ?